# Function to search in the array won't work?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I'm new to JS, and I'm trying to find out how a user can search for a number in an input box, and have the javascript alert the user where the number is in the array, or whether its not in the array at all. I have a link to my Fiddle, and the problem is the function in the lower half after the comment.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/83r24j3j/3/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

(And excuse me ahead of time for using `document.write`, some bad habits are hard to break.)

Comment: lowercase 'function' findNumber, and the capital N is missing in 'findumber'

Comment: Sorry, here is the updated Fiddle!http://jsfiddle.net/83r24j3j/5/

Comment: Re: `document.write`: unforgivable.  Break that habit!  For a beginner, I think learning some jQuery basics and using `.html` is a pretty easy way break the habit.

Comment: Where is `Search` defined. And you seem to be comparing a number to a DOM element, which doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Why did you remove all your code???

Comment: Sorry for removing the code, this is my first day on this website and I'm still trying to figure out how to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for findNumber ...

```
function findNumber() {
    Query = parseInt(document.getElementById(Search).value, 10);
    var index = NumberArray.indexOf(Query);
    if (index > -1) {
        alert(Query + " was found at position " + index);
    } else {
        alert(Query + " is not found in the array");
    }
}
```

First, you need to obtain the Query value inside the function.

Second, use `indexOf`, it's much more efficient.

Comment: Using `.indexOf()` to find a DOM element in an Array of numbers isn't going to work too well.

Comment: That works perfectly! thanks! Although now because I commit the great evil and use document.write, the printed values for the Array values, Sum, and average print over the input box and get rid of it. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @PhillipCharlesJackson: There's no `Search` variable, the code is looking for an element in an array of numbers, it shouldn't be comparing to -1. Everything about this code should fail. What made you think it works perfectly?

Comment: Forgot the `.value` on the query ... this could have been pointed out, but I got it.  Thanks.

Comment: It was pointed out. :-P But the other issues are that there's no `Search` variable, now that you have `.value`, you're looking for a string in an array of numbers, and you're still allowing equality to `-1`

Comment: Still invalid after edit, `index != -1` or `index > -1` are ok, but not `index >= -1`

Comment: Maybe instead if nitpicking it to death, someone could actually help on this system.

Answer (score 0):

```
var NumberArray = [5, 65, 02,9, 87, 65, 48, 6];

function findnumber() {
    var Query = document.getElementById('s').value;
    var f = false;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < NumberArray.length; i++) {
        if (Query == NumberArray[i]) {
            f = true; break; }
    }
    if(f) alert(Query + " was found at position " + i); else 
         alert(Query + "is not found in the array");
}
```

[**Demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/83r24j3j/13/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Oups, question has been edited a lot! So I need to tell this is an answer to [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27348248/2) of the question. I tried to fix things and answer while trying to keep close to the question code.

---

You have several mistakes in your code :

1. If you start a number with "0", it must be a valid octal value. So avoid `078`.
2. You have a spelling mistake in findNumber definition.
3. function vs "Function"
4. An improper way of doing things in findNumber (see below)
5. Bad transmission of the query to the function

Try this :

```js
    var NumberArray = [5, 65, 02, 04, 05, 80, 90, 01, 46, 87, 05, 6, 20, 48, 056, 78, 9, 7, 88, 9, 87, 65, 48, 6, 54, 3, 51, 90, 95, 60, 100];

    document.write("These are all of the numbers in the array");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(NumberArray);
    document.write("<hr>");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < NumberArray.length; i++) {
      sum += Number(NumberArray[i]);
      var average = sum / NumberArray.length;
    }

    document.write("This is the sum of the array");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(sum);
    document.write("<hr>");

    document.write("This is the average of the array");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(average);    

    function findNumber(Query) {
      for (i = 0; i < NumberArray.length; i++) {
        if (Query == NumberArray[i]) {
          alert(Query + " was found at position " + i);
          return;
        }
      }
      alert(Query + "is not found in the array");
    }

/* Not relevant here
    var lookingFor = prompt("who to look for?");
    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      if (lookingFor == people[i]) {
        alert(lookingFor + " was found at position " + i);
      }
    }
*/
```

```html
<title>
  Array Search Test
</title>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="Search" />
  <button onclick="findNumber(document.getElementById('Search').value);">Search Array</button>
  <hr />
  <script src="external.js"></script>
</body>
```

If you are a beginner at javascript, you should start with the smallest code possible and test frequently when you complexify things. Don't forget to read error messages in the console.

As a side note, I'd suggest you to learn the following :

1. Read a book like "JavaScript: The Good Parts" (by Douglas Crockford) first.
2. Learn the basics of jQuery, you would definitely easily avoid document.write and alert if you knew the basics of jQuery (although jQuery is not required).
3. After that, you may try to learn things more in-depth.